# Is there a maximum number of Azure DevOps Organizations per Azure Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am in the process of planning a transition to Azure DevOps for an ERP consulting company.  Our goal is to integrate Customer Stakeholders into Azure DevOps for faster feedback on requirements gathering and user acceptance testing.  In order to completely segregate customers I have decided that creating an Org per customer will be the best approach.  (Due to current stakeholder permission limitations: [User/Stakeholder has access to organization settings](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/485973/userstakeholder-has-access-to-organization-setting.html))

Before moving forward with this approach, I wanted to ensure that it can scale as our customer base continues to grow.  I have not been able identify a ceiling for Azure DevOps Organizations per Azure Active Directory.  Can anyone confirm if there is a limit?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the ceiling either. I can definitely attach multiple Orgs to the same Azure Tenant ID, and i have also associated multiple Orgs to the same Azure Subscription Enterprise Pay-As-You-Go as well.  I do not see any immediate limits under Usage + Quotas so i would say that there is no hard ceiling except for general resource limits in the subscription.

Associating the Org to the subscription allows you to manage non-free capabilities by tying it to an invoice.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no limitation for the number of azure devops organizations can be created per azure directory.

Microsoft only limits the free tier of resources in your organization.

The free tier includes:

- Five Azure DevOps users (Basic)
- Free tier of Microsoft-hosted CI/CD    (one concurrent job, up to 30 hours per month)
- 2GB of Azure Artifacts    storage
- One self-hosted CI/CD concurrent job
- 20,000 virtual user    minutes of cloud-based load testing

However, there are Work tracking, process, and project limits in azure devops. Please see document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops) for more information

Below document might be helpful:

[About organization management in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/organization-management?view=azure-devops)

[Multi-organization billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/billing-faq?view=azure-devops#multi-organization-billing)